# Cierre de función Scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

no estoy muy familiarizado con el lenguaje de programación scilab/matlab, al final me sale este error
endfunction
^~~~~~~~~~~^
Error: syntax error, unexpected endfunction, expecting end
Agradecería mucho su ayuda, y si me pueden sacar de la duda de paso, como podría anidar un ciclo en este lenguaje

```
    function [eslabones]=grashof(A,B,C,D)
    clc;
//Definición de la longitud de los eslabones
eslabones=[A,B,C,D];
a=eslabon(1); //manivela
b=eslabon(2); //acoplador 
c=eslabon(3); //seguidor
d=eslabon(4); // eslabon a tierra

tam=gsort(eslabones);

S=tam(1);
P=tam(2);
Q=tam(3);
L=tam(4);

//Definiciones de la estructura o mecanismo

if L>(S+P+Q)
     
    disp('No es posible este montaje');
  
    
elseif L==(S+P+Q)
    
    disp('Este montaje es una estructura');
    

endfunction
```

Comment: En Matlab las funciones se cierran con 'end' solamente,no con endfunction, otra cosa es que si solo retornas un parametro enmatlab no hace falta que lo encierres en  corchetes, ya que esto indica un vector de valores por retornar

Comment: Otra cosa es que en matlab todos los bucles o condicionales se cierran con 'end', puedes intentar agregar un 'end' despues del elseif para indicar que acabo el condicional.